# npm install => Cannot find type definition file for 'node'

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Just following the steps from [calendar](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/src/apis/calendar)
for building a browser bundle

cloning the repo => ok

then

```
$ cd src/apis/calendar
$ npm install
```

I get this error :

> @google/calendar@0.1.0 prepare /home/mick/projects/google-api-nodejs-client/src/apis/calendar
> npm run compile
> @google/calendar@0.1.0 compile /home/mick/projects/google-api-nodejs-client/src/apis/calendar
> tsc -p .
> node_modules/gaxios/build/src/common.d.ts:1:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

Comment: Have you considered following this https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 1):

try to delete `node_modules` folder then execute npm install

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: It does not... I don't what to do.